# Why do I have to use both .toString() and JSON.stringify()?

Tags: javascript, json, hash

```
const SHA256 = require("crypto-js/sha256");

// the possible colors that the hash could represent
const COLORS = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'pink', 'orange'];

// given a hash, return the color that created the hash
function findColor(hash) {
    let hashedColor;

    COLORS.forEach(color => {
        let hashedColor = SHA256(JSON.stringify(color)).toString();
        console.log(hashedColor);
        if (hashedColor === hash) {
            return color;
        };
    });
};


module.exports = findColor;
```

I'm experimenting with some hashing and manually using a rainbow table. When I import the SHA256 method, I find that I can create a hash for each of the colors but that this returns an object, which I then need to .stringify() to be able to console.log() the actual hash.

My question is, why do I have to both JSON.stringify() and .toString()?

I think I don't quite understand what data type the SHA256 function gives me, and I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: The methods might both return strings, but true JSON stringify will return JSON string, whereas the other toString method doesn’t.

Comment: Don't see why you are using JSON.stringify at all in this scenario

Comment: CryptoJS' `SHA256` method (along with each of its other hashing methods) returns a `WordArray` object, which is not explicitly interchangeable with a normal `String`. `toString()` is required to coerce the `WordArray` return value to a `String` for use in other contexts where strict type checking might be required. This is clearly documented in the [CryptoJS documentation](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#the-hashing-output), and it's not clear what part of the aforementioned documentation is unclear about this.

Comment: @esqew ahh I see thank you! So I don't need JSON.stringify?

Comment: @github292929 Not at all, and it's not clear where you got that idea. In fact, it will likely modify your input to `SHA256` function such that it's no longer what you intended to pass in.

Comment: `JSON.stringify` just adds quotes around the string

Comment: Probably got it from the usage doc for Crypto-JS:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js  But yes, it's not necessary here when you already have strings.

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.stringify()` is serializing the value of `color` as JSON.  This is required in most cases because your hash library can only do strings (or probably buffers too, but not just native objects).

However, you *already have* strings, and thus have no need to serialize the strings as JSON.  So, you can remove the extraneous `JSON.stringify()` here.